# a method to find the infinitesimal generator of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lie-groups

I have no background in one-parameter Lie group transformations associted to ODE's to construct the infinitesimal generator so I was wondering if there is some pratical method to find the infinitesimal generator of a first and second order diferential equation with constant coefficients using only the ODE itself. Does anyone have an idea or maybe  the answer ?  Thank you for your time.

Comment: In the second you have written down the generator, it is the right hand side of $y'=-Ay-B$. The first has to be transformed into a system of first order to have the form of the second.

Comment: in some documents I found that they define as $X=\eta (x,y) \frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\chi (x,y)  \frac{\partial}{\partial y}$  which is diffrent from the one you gave here, are they two diffrent things ? or there is a relation between them ?